# join between content type in a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I created a content type: Map that has a field "node reference" on which I can select the name of another type of content type. It also has an Image field.

Now, I want create a View. The view must have below every field image Map a data field that is in the content type reference

I need help to set the View ...
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the view page. Under `Relationships` section, click to add a new one.

Choose `Entity Reference: Referenced Entity` that has a description `A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via THE_FIELD_REFERENCE`.

In the fields section click to add a new field. Choose your image field and click Add, under `Relationships` choose the relationship you've just created.

Now, the image should appear in the view.

Hope this works... Muhammad.